# WPF: Putting a DataGrid in a ComboBox

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox

In WPF, how can I put a DataGrid in a ComboBox to show multiple columns? Stuff like the following doesn't seem to do anything:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding customerName}" />                 
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding billingAddress}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: What does the model you are adding to the combobox look like

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you're referring to the ViewModel property I'm binding my ComboBox's ItemSource to, it is a List<Of MyCumstomerBO>.

Comment: I just wanted to see the `MyCumstomer` object, so I can see if this is possible, or do you have a picture of what you are trying to create, I may be able to help

Comment: sure. it is a simple C# class like this:

   Class CustomerBO
        Public Property customerID As String
        Public Property customerName As String
        Public Property billingAddress As String
        Public Property billingCity As String
        ...
    End Class

Comment: ah, comments lose formatting.

Comment: So what lists go in the DataGrid?, or does the ComboBox just have one DataGrid and all the items go into the datagrid, I dont see sub collections to poulate the Datagrid only strings.

Comment: A List<CustomerBO> that is created by querying the database.

Comment: So there is a List<CustomerBO> foe each datagrid? so your comboBox itemsource is `List<List<CustomerBO>>`

Comment: yes. that's correct. There's a single list that should fill the dropdown because the ComboBox's standard dropdown can't show grid-like columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for this, I found one implementation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43074/WPF-Custom-ComboBox).

Answer (score 0):

```
<ComboBox Width="150" Height="30" Name="cb">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGridRow DataContext="{Binding}" Height="30" Width="150">
                        <DataGridRow.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid> 
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding customerName}" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
                                    <Border  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2"></Border>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding billingAddress}" Margin="2"></TextBlock>
                                </Grid>

                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </DataGridRow.Template>

                    </DataGridRow>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: This kills the very ComboBox. Now I don't see either the dropdown button or the dropdown itself.

Comment: I see that. What we need here is some way to modify the the Itemtemplate of combobox. But if we put Datagrid in to the ItemTemplate, every item of combobox will act like a DataGrid. I have tried something here, see if this is manageable.